# MaxMind GeoIP2 no results for IPv6?

Tags: php, ipv6, geoip

I have downloaded https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php and the database http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/ to catch the timezone for a page visitor.

```
require_once('GeoIp2/vendor/autoload.php');

$reader = new Reader('GeoIp2/GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
$record = $reader->city($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $record->location->timeZone;
```

Its working fine with IPv4, but IPv6 is not working. The output is empty with no errors. Is here somthing missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every IP address is associated with a time zone. This is particularly an issue for IPv6 addresses where the geolocation data is more spotty. Given that you are getting a record back, I'd suspect that the IP only has country-level data without a time zone. You could add an `echo json_encode($record);` your file to see what data is in the lookup.